# React+Redux: bug where component unmounts on render only when code is minified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, uglifyjs

Environment: React 16.3, Redux 3.7.2, Webpack 4.6.0, UglifyJS plugin for Webpack 1.2.5.

I am trying to solve a bug that only occurs when we build with NODE_ENV='production' (which turns on minification using the UglifyJS webpack plugin via `mode: 'production'`).

The component hierarchy looks roughly (minus a bunch of `div`s) like:

`Sidebar
   SidebarSection (array)
     SidebarSubSection (array)
       Field (e.g. InputField)`

Both SidebarSection and SidebarSubSection components are created with unique `key` attributes. When an onChange event handler for a field is triggered, it updates the model through a redux reducer, which triggers a re-render of Sidebar and child components. In development, this all works fine but in production (with minification) we are getting bugs that are caused by the SidebarSubSection being unmounted/re-mounted along with all the child fields.

According to https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html this shouldn't be happening given that the types in the tree aren't changing and that we are using keys on the arrays of components.

Tweaking things like `keep_classnames` on the uglify compress options hasn't helped.

My specific configuration for uglifyjs under `optimization`: 

`minimizer: [
   new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMaps: true,
      uglifyOptions: {
         ecma: 8,
         compress: {
            dead_code: true,
            unused: true,
            inline: false,
            global_defs: {
              'process.env.NODE_ENV': 'production'
            }
         }
      }
   })
]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear, if you build it for production, but just leave out the uglify process, do you still observe the bug? Basically, are you 100% certain it's the minification part of the production build that is causing it?

Comment: Yes. If I alter the webpack config to `{ optimization: { minimize: false } }` the bug does not appear. Right now it is:

Comment: See my current config above